# Move elements when they overlap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am have a issue with elements overlapping. I have a navbar that is sticky so it slides down the page when scrolling. I also have a to-top button that will auto to you to the header when hit. What I am wanting to do is when my to-top button reaches inside the header when scrolling right now it hovers over the last social icon on the far right. I want it to move the social icons over to fit in the to-top button. I am using the uikit from uikit.com to build it.

Comment: please provide a jsfiddle with your code, otherwise it is not really possible to help you. Have you looked into the CSS `z-index` property?

Answer (score 0):

You can detect scrolling past a certain (google it), and then use jquery to relocate the buttons that are being hidden.